# Prevent Outlook (Web) Style Change on Street Address

Tags: html, html-email, email-templates, outlook-web-app

I'm working with a basic HTML email template.  At the end of the message, a street address is included.

When I open the email in Outlook web; it detects the address and re-styles it into a Bing map link.

Is there anyway to preserve the styles I set?

```
<p style="font-family: Garamond, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
    123 E. Main St. SomeTown, USA 12345-6789
</p>
```

Comment: I don't think you can disable this from the email side. You can disable the Bing plugin on your end, though. See [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-disable-the-bing-maps-search-function-in/8a5aebfb-5240-46fd-8ff0-3499bd216962).

Comment: @BramVanroy that's what I was afraid of :P but I wanted to hit up StackOverflow to see if there was some magic solution I may have missed.  thanks for confirming.

Comment: There might be, I'm just not aware of it. Maybe someone else can provide you with some more hopeful information. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not disable links in a few email clients but there are walkarounds for these.

1. You can use zero width non-joiner `&zwnj;`
2. Use CSS to make it look like normal text
3. User meta tags (for iOS)

**Gmail:**

**Option 1:**

Wrap your telephone number or address in a span tag and use a global CSS to target it.

```css
.address{color:#000001; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
    <p style="font-family: Garamond, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
        <span class="address">123 E. Main St. SomeTown, USA 12345-6789</span>
    </p>
```

Reason is Gmail adds CSS that colors a href

```
.ii a[href] { color: #15c; }
```

You might be able to overwrite this with your CSS as well (give it a try).

**Option 2:**

You can use a CSS to overwrite all link styling, forcing it to inherit the style from the parent.

```css
u + #body a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

**iOS:**

**Option 1:**

Use meta tag to disable links

```
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
```

**Option 2:**

Use zero-width-non-joiner (`&zwnj;`)

```
<p style="font-family: Garamond, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
    1&zwnj;2&zwnj;3 E. Main St. SomeTown, USA 12345-6789
</p>
```

**Option 3:**

Styling the tel url scheme (also works for Android)

```
a[href^=tel]{ color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
```

**Option 4:**

Styling mail's data detector selector

```css
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family: Garamond, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
    123 E. Main St. SomeTown, USA 12345-6789
</p>
```

Hope this helps in answering your question.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer :)